# Обновить базу один раз

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `turnir` ORDER BY `win` DESC LIMIT 1";
$turnir_win = mysql_query($query);
while($turnir_row_win = mysql_fetch_array($turnir_win)){
    $ress_mon = $data_user['money'] + $turnir_settings_row['baks_win'];
    $ress_raiting = $data_user['raiting'] + $turnir_settings_row['raiting_win'];
    $query = "UPDATE
                users
              SET
                money = '$ress_mon',
                raiting = '$ress_raiting'
              WHERE
               `id` = $turnir_row_win[id_user]";
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_query());
}
```

Вот код. Мне нужно, чтобы он обновлял только один раз, а он обновляет каждый раз при обновлении. Как сделать, чтобы один раз обновлял?

Comment: @anonymous_911_, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: И что именно он должен один раз обновлять? У вас цикл, в цикле обновляются какие-то данные. Отформатируйте правильно текст и задайте правильно вопрос.!

Answer (score 2):

Может быть проблема в том, что `WHERE id = $turnir_row_win[id_user]"` каждый раз выбирает несколько строк, а должно одну? А вообще, такие вещи лучше делать одним `SQL`-запросом, без цикла на `PHP`